# How to partially create a type

Tags: haskell, monads

I am trying to create my `Btree` monad and i do not know how to define the `return` for this since , i want to put the value in the `Node (Leaf value)` and leave the other branch empty.

```
module Tree where 
    import Control.Monad

    data Btree a=Node (Btree a)(Btree a)|Leaf a
```

The problem arises if i want to inject a value in the Monad:

```
    instance Monad Btree  where 
      (>>=) (Leaf x) f = f x
      (>>=) (Node a b) f=Node (a>>=f) (b>>=f)
      return t=Node (Leaf t)  # i want to partially apply `Node` to not have to specify the other branch . Do i need an additional ADT  ?  `Leaf/Node/Root` ? for single elements ?
```

**P.S** When trying to run this with `return=Leaf` or `return t=Node (Leaf t)(Leaf t)` i also get the error:

```
* No instance for (Applicative Btree)
        arising from the superclasses of an instance declaration
    * In the instance declaration for `Monad Btree'
```

Comment: surely it should just be `return t = Leaf t` (or, equivalently, `return = Leaf`) ?

Comment: just seen your edit, as it says you have to make the type an instance of Applicative (and before that, Functor), before you make the Monad instance. (Note that whatever you define as `pure` here - which should be `Leaf` - will become the `return` definition for the `Monad` instance, so you don't have to define it again.)

Comment: You can not partially apply `Node` and get a tree: if you do, you get a function, since that's what partial application is for. In this case, you don't need `Node`, you can simply use `Leaf t` for a tree with only one leaf.

Comment: While `return = Leaf` has presented you with another error it is correct and you have gotten further in your implementation.  Keep `return = Leaf` and now fix this next issue instead of going backwards.

Comment: Your problem is that you want to write down various instances for a binary tree and you don’t know how/are running into difficulties or errors. You should try to make sure that when you ask a question it focuses on how to solve your problem rather than how to solve the difficulties you run into with your attempted solution. The reason is that it may be that your attempted solution will never work and so any answer won’t be useful to you, and the difficulty you run into typically won’t be relevant to anyone else (or indeed yourself).

Comment: [Related?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6798699/4942760)