# Implementing monad on recursive type

Tags: haskell, monads

I have a recursive type: 
`data E a=A a (E a) (E a) | None`
My problem is the following :
If i want to implement the `bind` operator how do i operate on both the Concrete type and the recursive one given the function to operate with?

```
instance Monad E where
    return x= A x None None 
    (>>=) None _ = None
    (>>=) (B t) f =  f t
    (>>=) (A x mx my) f = A {f x} (mx>>=f)  (my>>=f) --here !!!
                               ^
                            result is ma but slot requires concrete type
```

For me to apply `>>=` on  `A a (E a) (E a)` for the `a` it seems i  need to unwrap it using a custom made `function`.

How do i solve the `{f x}`so that i unwrap the result of `f x` to fit in the concrete slot of the `E`

I would need for a method that can take a function: `a-> ma` and get it to `(ma ->a)`

```
    unwrap::E a->a
    unwrap None= what here ? ( i need a neutral element for any kind of a)
    unwrap (A x _ _)=x
```

Comment: Well your `f x` will return something of type `E a` here, so you can just implement a functoin that "unpacks" the data constructor, and performs operations with it.

Comment: Did you mean `instance Monad E where ...`?

Comment: That should also be `None >>= _ = None`, not `_ >>= None = None`.

Comment: If you ignore the `B` constructor, this looks like a list, so you might get some inspiration by looking at the `Monad []` implementation.  What is this data type supposed to represent -- what do the various constructors `A`, `B`, `None` mean?

Comment: `B` itself is somewhat redundant; `B` is basically `flip A None`.

Comment: I am sorry i wanted to represent something like a tree, but i wanted to simplify it with only one branch since i was interested only in the last case : dealing with a type constructor  that has a data constructor which holds both a concrete type and a [Type constructor] concrete_type. `data SomeType a=Ctor1 a (SomeType a) |......`

Comment: To reemphasize, you don't need a separate leaf constructor if you allow for empty trees with `None`: a leaf is just an `A` with no subtrees, `A x None None`. Probable duplicate: [Monad instance for binary tree](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6798699/1126841).

Comment: I have updated my original post.However now my free variable must be a monoid is that not true ?

Comment: Your `unwrap` strategy is not going to work. The essence is to "reshuffle" `m (m a)` to an `m a`, preserving all the information.  It is not usually possible to pass through `m a -> a` because that throws away information.

Comment: So what can i do with the free variable that is not an `ma` ?  How do i go from `a` -> `m a` , apply the `f` and get it back to `a` , since clearly i have a data with both `[Constructor]  a  (m a)`

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian, it is not necessarily easy (fyi I do not see a solution); for many types it is not possible at all. Your `f x` returns a tree, and you also have the two trees you got from binding the children `mx>>=f` and `my>>=f`.  You need to decide what goes at the root of the result. What should go there? The root of `f x`? What if `f x` is empty? These questions need answers, and you get these answers from your *intention*. What is this data type a model of?

Comment: Its a binary tree , with some data stored at each node.

Comment: @BercoviciAdrian, does that answer what to put at the root of the tree that bind returns?  What makes you think a binary tree is a monad?

Comment: I thought i could make it , if only i could unwrap the root. (Still learning)

Answer (score 3):

To overcome your specific challenge, you should try pattern matching on the result of `f x`.

```
(>>=) (A x mx) f = 
    case f x of
        A y my -> 
        B y -> 
        None ->
```

Now you have perhaps a larger problem than the one you came in with.  There are now too many choices, as opposed to a poverty of them.  In the `A y my` case, you must combine `y`, `my`, and `mx` into the final result in some way.  Very likely most of the ways you think of will violate the laws.

In this case it is hard to know what to do.  It is hard for me to implement a monad unless I am clear about the *meaning* of the data type.  I can "visualize" list as a monad because `join` (aka `(>>= id)`) is just concatenation

```
join :: [[a]] -> [a]
join [ [ x, y ], [z], [], [w, q] ] = [x, y, z, w, q]
```

But for an arbitrary algebraic data type there is no clear path.  Where did this data type come from? -- what do you want from its monad instance?

Comment: Perhaps some intuition can be obtained using `data F a k = A a k | None` and then defining `type E a = Free (F a)`. Here, `Pure` would play the role of `B` in the original type. This, however, is probably NOT what the OP wants (?).