# Is the type constructor `Maybe (BTree a)` a monad?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads, category-theory

### Question

Define the type constructor `F` in Haskell like this:

```
 data BTree a = Leaf a | Branch (BTree a) (BTree a)
 data F a = F (Maybe (BTree a))
```

The type constructor `F` is polynomial, so it is a `Functor`, an `Applicative`, a `Traversable`, but not obviously a `Monad`.

Can we implement `bind` and `return` for `F` that satisfy the monad laws and thus make `F` into a monad? Or is that impossible?

### Motivation

The question is motivated by the fact that `F` is a generator of data structures of a special kind. Namely, certain `F`-algebras are monoids that may violate the associativity law. More rigorously, the type `F t` is an initial object in the category of not-quite-monoids generated by type `t` that may violate the associativity law.

To see why:

First, we can define the monoid-like operations on `F a`. The empty element is `F Nothing` and the binary operation puts two values into the branches of a tree unless one of the values is empty.

Second, suppose the type `T` is an `F`-algebra, so we have `h: F T -> T`. This means we have `h(F Nothing)`, which is a value of type `T` that serves as the empty value of the monoid, and we have a binary operation `(T, T) -> T` defined by `\(x,y) -> h(F(Just(Branch(Leaf x) (Leaf y))))`. Further, suppose that `h` preserves the monoid operations, then `h` will also preserve the identity laws. So, `T` is a not-quite-monoid that satisfies the identity laws (but may violate the associativity law).

`F` looks like the tree monad `BTree(Maybe a)` factored by the identity laws of a monoid, although I don't have a formal way of deriving `F` from that.

The usual folklore knowledge is that `F`-algebras with laws need to be described via monad algebras. But if `F` is not a monad then that is not true. The typeclass laws need to be described in a more general way.

But the main question is: can we make `F` into a monad?

Comment: Doesn't look like a monad to me. How would you flatten `F (F int)` to `F int`? Say you have `F(Just (Branch (F(Just (Leaf 42))), F Nothing)`, what the result should be?

Comment: @n.m. Perhaps the result should be `F(Just(Leaf(42)))`. Right now I am not sure either way, whether `F` can be a monad or not. One should implement `bind` and check the laws.

Comment: Hmm I thought such definition would violate one law or the other but apparently it doesn't, or I cannot find a counterexample.

Comment: There is a somewhat related discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6798699/monad-instance-for-binary-tree)

Comment: I deleted my answer because I misread your datatype, sorry about that. I agree it looks like a Monad. I guess you could use quickcheck tests to verify.

Answer (score 3):

`F` is indeed a monad. Given that it is the composition of `Maybe` with `BTree`, with both being monads and `BTree` being traversable, we can tentatively make it a monad using the composed-on-the-inside transformer instance:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GHC2021 #-}
import Control.Monad (join, ap)

newtype F a = F { runF :: Maybe (BTree a) }
    deriving (Eq, Show, Ord, Functor, Foldable, Traversable)

instance Monad F where
    m >>= f = F
        $ fmap (join @BTree) . join @Maybe . fmap (sequenceA @BTree)
        $ runF $ runF . f <$> m

instance Applicative F where
    pure = F . pure @Maybe . pure @BTree
    (<*>) = ap

data BTree a = Leaf a | Branch (BTree a) (BTree a)
    deriving (Eq, Show, Ord, Functor, Foldable, Traversable)

instance Monad BTree where
    Leaf a >>= f = f a
    Branch la ra >>= f = Branch (la >>= f) (ra >>= f)

instance Applicative BTree where
    pure = Leaf
    (<*>) = ap
```

For details on this transformer construction, see the "Flipped transformers and the Eilenberg-Moore adjunction" section of [my answer to *Do monad transformers, generally speaking, arise out of adjunctions?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56726855/2751851) In particular, that section points out there two conditions which must hold for the `Monad F` instance above to be lawful. Firstly, `join @Maybe` must preserve `(<*>)`, that is:

```
join' :: Monad m => Compose m m a -> m a
join' = join . getCompose
```

```
mmf :: Compose Maybe Maybe (a -> b)
mma :: Compose Maybe Maybe a

join' (mmf <*> mma) = join' mmf <*> join' mma
```

The  difference between the two sides of this equation boils down to the order in which the effects from `mmf` and `mma` are sequenced. Since `Maybe` is a commutative monad, that doesn't matter, and the condition holds.

Secondly, `join @BTree` must preserve `toList`, that is:

```
bba :: Compose BTree BTree a

toList bba = toList (join' bba)
```

Since `BTree` is a free monad (of the homogeneous pair functor), its `join` does nothing but grafting trees to remove the nesting, with no rearrangement of elements from the point of view of `toList`. That being so, this second condition holds as well, and therefore `F` is a monad.

P.S.: Regarding [n. m.'s question in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75771647/is-the-type-constructor-maybe-btree-a-a-monad/75909703#comment133664128_75771647):

> Say you have `F(Just (Branch (F(Just (Leaf 42))), F Nothing)`, what the result should be?

The core part of the `(>>=)` definition, which amounts to `join` sans the boilerplate, is:

```
fmap (join @BTree) . join @Maybe . fmap (sequenceA @BTree)
```

From that, we can tell that `join` will behave as in `BTree` if all `Maybe` values are `Just` in `F (F a)`. If there is a `Nothing` anywhere, though, the result will be `Nothing`, as `sequenceA` and `join @Maybe` will propagate failure:

```
ghci> join $ F (Just (Branch (Leaf (F (Just (Leaf 42)))) (Leaf (F Nothing))))
F {runF = Nothing}
```

Comment: What's this `@` syntax?

Comment: @Bergi It comes from [the `TypeApplications` extension](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/9.6.1/docs/users_guide/exts/type_applications.html). It is not required here -- I'm using it solely for expository reasons, to make it clear which instance is being used at each step in the denser parts of the code.

Comment: Thanks, it didn't seem necessary but very useful indeed. I haven't done any Haskell for quite some time so I figured it must be new (or very advanced :P)